# Java does not find sql file

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception

I have a Java application that uses SQLite as a Database. I want to execute some setup queries that are stored in a file called "setup.sql".

I call the following code to read the file:

> BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
> FileReader(Resources.SETUP.file)))

`Resources.SETUP.file` is an enum that stores the file paths, in this case to "sql/setup.sql" located in the resources folder of my project.

I use this scheme for other files like images and localization, which works perfectly, like the following example for the logo image (Enum is "images/logo.png"):

> Image logoImage = new Image(Resources.LOGO.file);

However with the sql file I always get a `FileNotFoundException`.

Am I using the Readers incorrectly?

The following does not work:

> getClass().getResource(Resources.SETUP.file); -> InvocationTargetException
>
> getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(Resources.SETUP.file); -> FileNotFoundException

Comment: `getClass().getResource(Resources...))`

Comment: That does not work. Plus, please provide the duplicate you claim it shoud be.

Comment: Using getClassLoader returns the correct url, however I still have a FileNotFoundException

Comment: Are you using Maven to package and run your code? Is the file being copied into your classpath? I.e. When you run the code, the `src/main/resources` folder isn't what's being read from

Comment: If I remeber correctly `new Image()` takes resource from class path, while `FileReader()` expects a path in file system, either absolute or relative to directory from where JVM started. So if you use maven and run it in IDE path should be `src/main/resources/sql/setup.sql`. Still remember it is relative to directory from where `java` command called.

Comment: The FileNotFoundException shows the path /Users/.../.../target/classes/sql/setup.sql which is where that file is (after compilation)

Comment: The file is also in the jar archive at the correct location. And yes I use maven.